# How do you run moba Infinite Crisis game through Wine?

Tags: software-installation, games

So is it me or does no one know the moba infinite crisis? Because I ant seem to get help with this game so I have just assumed that no one in the Linux community has the power to get this game to work...am I right?

And yes wine hq doesnt help and is out of date on this matter.

Comment: Most current WineHQ entry says it can install, but not run. https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30746

Comment: that wine entry is out of date.

Comment: yes, but then you should create a new one. This question is not even about Ubuntu, but about getting a game to run in Wine.